# Show that $I-A$ is non-singular

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

I am trying to show that $I-A$ is non-singular, but I am having difficulty. I know that $A$ ($p \times p$) is a skew symmetric matrix ($A^T=-A$) and that all the elements of $A$ are real. We are given a tip that for complex  $\textbf{x}$ we have $\textbf{x}^H \textbf{x} = 0 \Rightarrow \textbf{x} = 0$.

My approach was to use a theorem that states: For a square matrix $A$ and a real or complex $\textbf{x}$ then $A$ is non-singular if $\textbf{x} = 0$ is the only solution to $A \textbf{x} = 0$.

Here is my approach:

Lets say we have $(I-A)\textbf{x}=0$ to show that $(I-A)$ is non-singular it suffices to show that $\textbf{x}=0$. Distribute the $\textbf{x}$

$$\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}=0$$

then multiply on the left by $\textbf{x}^H$ and apply $\textbf{x}^H \textbf{x} = 0$

$$\textbf{x}^H\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}^HA\textbf{x}=0 \Rightarrow \textbf{x}^HA\textbf{x}=0$$
At this point I use brute force
$$\textbf{x}^HA\textbf{x}=0 \Rightarrow \textbf{x}^H \textbf{b} = 0$$ 
where $b_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}x_i a_{ji}$ for $j=1,...,p$. Next
$$\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\bar{x}_k b_k \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\bar{x}_k \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}x_i a_{ki}\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}\bar{x}_k x_i a_{ki} = 0$$

Does this then imply that each (from what I understand each term would have to be positive for this to be true)
$$\bar{x}_k x_i a_{ki} = 0 , \forall k,i = 1,...,p$$
If it did my next step would be to divide by $a_{ki}$ and $\bar{x}_k$ to get
$$x_i  = 0 , \forall i = 1,...,p \Rightarrow \textbf{x}=0$$ which shows the $(I-A)$ is non singular.

Is this sufficient in proving the claim?

Also, thank God that the Mathematics stack exchange saves work when the browser crashes. I was nearly finished with this when my browser crashed and I thought I lost everything :).

Comment: In your first paragraph: by "...all the values of $A$ are real..." do you mean the entries of the matrix are real numbers?

Comment: Exactly. I will fix that up.

Comment: Does $x^H$ mean the conjugate transpose or something?

Comment: "apply $x^Hx=0$": you've assumed that $x=0$, which is what we were supposed to prove.

Comment: @Mike its the Hermitian(complex conjugate) transpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing you proof from $(I-A)x=0$, we conclude that $Ax=x$. Also, $x^HAx=x^Hx\in\mathbb{R}$, hence
$$\|x\|^2 = x^Hx = x^HAx = (x^HAx)^H = x^HA^Hx = x^HA^Tx = - x^HAx = -x^Hx = -\|x\|^2,$$
implying $x=0$.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what strategy you used to get to the conclusion. Did you just look at the hint at build your argument from that? I ask because I am awful at proofs, and am trying to get better, so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: As in other cases with linear algebra, the main thing is to put everything that was given into the same argument, and trust in the god of proofs that things will work out okay ;). There could certainly be some level of intuition gained working with eigenvalues/eigenvectors in the choice to use the inner product of $x,Ax$ (note how @E.O. and I both basically built the argument around his equation $(1)$).

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ only has real entries, we know that $A^H=-A$ and so 
$$\mathbf{x}^HA^H\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{x}^HA\mathbf{x} \hspace{5mm} (1)$$
Now suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$$\mathbf{x}^HA^H\mathbf{x}=(A\mathbf{x})^H\mathbf{x}=(\lambda\mathbf{x})^H\mathbf{x}=\bar{\lambda}\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}$$
and
$$-\mathbf{x}^HA\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{x}^H\lambda\mathbf{x}=-\lambda\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}$$
From $(1)$ you know that $-\lambda\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}=\bar{\lambda}\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}$. This means $-\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$ and so $\lambda$ cannot be $1$. It follows by the definition of eigenvalues that $I-A$ is non-singular.

Comment: Very nice! (one comment: one could stop after noting that $\lambda=1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $A$)

Comment: @JonathanY. indeed, I'll edit my answer :-)

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I don't think we are supposed to be using eigenvalues yet.

Comment: Why can the Identity subtraction move inside the multiplication? Why can we subtract before the multiplication of matrices?